# UILabel in TableCell never changes font or colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uilabel, uitableview

I've been trying to find a solution for this for quite some time now but with no luck. I've got a `TableViewController` with a number of Cells, all of which have a `UILabel` with some text. I'm trying to change the font and colour with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:12.0f];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

This code should be correct to set the font and colour to a `UILabel` but it just never changes. Maybe there's a setting I need to change from the `Interface Builder`? Maybe an attribute setting the I need to disable?

The odd part is that even from the `Interface Builder` the fonts and colours simply never change.

Comment: Where are you assigning the text of this UILabel? I suspect the textLabel property of UITableViewCell is not referencing the same UILabel that you want to change. The above code is working for me, however I set the text property first to test - cell.textLabel.text = @"Testing changes";

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware that just text in the Interface Builder wasn't enough for fonts to change.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:-

```
@interface TestTableViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation TestTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tableView.delegate=self;
  self.tableView.dataSource=self;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString * reuseIdentifier = nil ;
    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:12.0f];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number: %d",indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, just tried it out but still nothing

Comment: I just edited the answer. Make sure that you have the <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> on the header and also set your view controller as the the delegate and datasource in viewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks a lot for this, it worked only now when selected nothing happens :/ They all had a segue to show another TableRowController

Comment: What do you mean? I thought you only want to make the text color and font for Cells? If you need something else, can you please update your question?

Comment: thanks for this but managed to solve the issue. The text was manual added from the Interface Builder, as @Bamsworld commented assigning the text through code solved the issue.